# HTTP status if re-authentication is required

Tags: http, authentication, access-token, http-status-codes, http-status-code-401

Which status code would you use in this scenario, assuming you're using a token based authentication:

1. The **client** has a token and makes a **request** to the server.
2. The **token expired** and the **server sends** a **401** Unauthorized.
3. The **client sends** the **refresh token**.
4. The **token is invalid** and the server responds with XXX?

The use case would be an application, that automatically catches 401's and makes a request with the refresh token. If the server would respond with a 401 if this token is not valid, the client would try to request a new access token with the refresh token forever. But it should tell the client, that it should re-authenticate with its credentials (e.g. email and password).

I was just wondering which status code would be the best fit in this scenario, as the spec says in case of a 403 Forbidden "authorization will not help".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not make access and refresh tokens interchangeable: Use Access-Tokens to access protected resources and use Refresh-Token to fetch new Access-Token from a special end-point. OpenID Connect works this way.

You would have one HTTP request more but HTTP codes would not be a problem and, in my opinion, you would get a cleaner code.